# Events in scriptable objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to use UnityEvents and/or UnityActions in scriptable objects? 
My attempt looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

[CreateAssetMenu(menuName ="Dog", fileName ="New Dog")]
public class Dog : ScriptableObject
{
    public string Id;
    public string Text;
    public UnityEvent WhenFinished;
    public GameObject Go;


}
```

Is it possible to make a scriptable object hold a reference to a GO in the hierarchy or have an event point to a listener in the hierarchy. Is there anyway a scriptable object can communicate with the logic in the hierarchy?

Comment: I don't believe it's possible in that direction. You can of course do the opposite, and have an object in the hierarchy hold a reference to the scriptableobject.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.
You can get an SO to GO reference and the reverse, but only during runtime.
When outside runtime, you can only get a SO to GO reference, an SO created in the editor outside of runtime can't reference any game object (it wouldn't know from which scene to get the GO).

Following is the code showing how to achieve this.

**Scriptable Object Code**

```cs
using System;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "Dog", fileName = "New Dog")]
public class Dog : ScriptableObject {
    public GameObject Go;
    public static event Action<string> ScriptableToGameobjectEvent;

    private void Awake() {
        EventScript.GameobjectToScriptableEvent += InstanceCreated;     
        if (Application.isPlaying) {
            ScriptableToGameobjectEvent("Dog Created");
        }
    }

    private void InstanceCreated(GameObject go) {
        Go = go;
        Debug.Log(Go.name);
    }
}
```

**Game Object Code**

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class EventScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public static event Action<GameObject> GameobjectToScriptableEvent;
    public ScriptableObject myScriptable;

    private void Awake() {
        Dog.ScriptableToGameobjectEvent += DogCreated;
    }

    private void Start() {      
        myScriptable = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<Dog>();
    }

    private void DogCreated(string str) {
        Debug.Log(str);
        GameobjectToScriptableEvent(gameObject);
    }
}
```